# Track Click Issue - Email studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, send-email, email-tracking

I did an email send test with Track Clicks, the result of this was the tracked email links returns to error page saying "Your Connection is not private":  [image]

Message translated:

"click.x.com.br uses encryption to protect your information. When Microsoft Edge tried to connect to click.x.com.br this time, the site sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This can happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be click.x.com.br, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still safe because Microsoft Edge stopped the connection before any data exchange.

It is not possible to visit click.x.com.br at the moment because the site uses HSTS. Errors and network attacks are usually temporary, so this page will likely work later."

Although I descelect Track Clicks from the box the email are sended.

someone already has been passed by it? How to solve that problem? I need to able track to do the reports. The SAP has been already configured a long time ago.

Our Domain SSL Certificates:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you shared explains the issue quite well: you are missing SSL certificates securing your URLs. When you click on your tracking links in the email, the URL generated is not https:// but http:// - hence the warning in your browser.

If you have purchased SSL certificates as part of your license, you can secure the URLs yourself:

1. Navigate to Setup, then search for and select **Domain SSL Certificates**.
2. Click the action arrow next to a domain, then select **Secure this Domain**.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_august_2021_ssl_self_serve.htm&type=5)

More details on how to do it, can be found in [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/self-serve-ssl-certificates-in-marketing-cloud-quick-look/claim-an-ssl-certificate-for-your-custom-domain).